# Test Drive Unlimited 2 Custom radio

Tags: ps3, test-drive-unlimited-2

In test TDU, it was possible to hook up his iphone to the console (ie xbox 360) and a custom radio channel appeared in the game so you can play your own track from the ipod.

Is it possible to do the same with TDU2 on PS3 ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that PS3 owners are able to make custom radio stations. Although there is a work around for PC and 360 owners [here](http://www.pubarticles.com/article-how-to-play-your-own-music-in-test-drive-unlimited-2-1296114900.html). I have not tried this so I don't know if it works or not.